# Avada theme, Wordpress, Header Customization

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, customization

I am having an issue with avada theme. I am not managing to solve myself.

For the specific case of the site I am working on I need to have the logo centered and inline with the menu (3 menu < li >, logo, 3 menu < li >).
I can't find where to modify the final HTML file the theme produces, does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance. And  sorry if I made any mistakes, this is not my language!

Comment: do you have a link to your site?

Comment: http://bnana.it/faletta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in your header tag

```
    <header id="header">
            <div style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;" class="avada-row">

                            <nav class="nav-holder" id="nav">
                                <ul class="menu" id="nav">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-22" id="menu-item-22"><a href="http://bnana.it/faletta">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21" id="menu-item-21"><a href="http://bnana.it/faletta/cascina/">Cascina</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20" id="menu-item-20"><a href="http://bnana.it/faletta/cantina/">Cantina</a></li>
    <li><div style="margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:0px;" class="logo">
                    <a href="http://bnana.it/faletta">
                        <img class="normal_logo" alt="Cascina Faletta" src="http://bnana.it/faletta/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/logo_prova1.png">
                                        </a>
                </div></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19" id="menu-item-19"><a href="http://bnana.it/faletta/cucina/">Cucina</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18"><a href="http://bnana.it/faletta/soggiorno/">Soggiorno</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17" id="menu-item-17"><a href="http://bnana.it/faletta/contatti/">Contatti</a></li>
            </ul>
                <div id="undefined" class="dd-container" style="width: 100%;"><div class="dd-select" style="width: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(238, 238, 238);"><input type="hidden" class="dd-selected-value" value=""><a class="dd-selected"><label class="dd-selected-text">Go to...</label></a><span class="dd-pointer dd-pointer-down"></span></div><ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close" style="width: 100%;"><li><a class="dd-option dd-option-selected"> <label class="dd-option-text">Go to...</label></a></li><li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="http://bnana.it/faletta" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Home</label></a></li><li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="http://bnana.it/faletta/cascina/" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Cascina</label></a></li><li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="http://bnana.it/faletta/cantina/" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Cantina</label></a></li><li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="http://bnana.it/faletta/cucina/" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Cucina</label></a></li><li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="http://bnana.it/faletta/soggiorno/" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Soggiorno</label></a></li><li><a class="dd-option"> <input type="hidden" value="http://bnana.it/faletta/contatti/" class="dd-option-value"> <label class="dd-option-text">Contatti</label></a></li></ul></div></nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! that's exactly what I meant, but didn't know how to write it! Thanks a lot, great and very quick help!